# CSS box-shadow on three sides of a div?

Tags: css

I want to have box-shadow on three sides of a div (except top side). How could I do that?

Comment: It's a dupe, but this one has a better answer in my opinion.  Can they be merged?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36aaL/2/) for you, it only uses one single div to work.

```
#shadowBox {
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px gray, 
        -10px 8px 15px gray, 10px 8px 15px gray;
}
```

You set a shadow on the bottom, bottom left, and bottom right. With soft shadows it gets a bit tricky but it is doable. It just needs a bit of guesswork to decrease the middle shadow's blur radius, so that it looks seamless and not too dark when it overlaps with the side shadows.

Comment: couldn't you get the same effect just by adjusting the y position of 1 box shadow?

Comment: @Vigrond I tried that, it doesn't make the shadow blur drop off of the sides far enough. You need to add two corner shadows to make the sides more even.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, this seems to stack three separate box-shadows on top of each other, making each edge much darker than expected. Isn't there a way to add a single shadow to each side, or one shadow that will cover all three?

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for something like Google material design shadows:

```
.shadow1 {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.shadow2 {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
.shadow3 {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
.shadow4 {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
.shadow5 {
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@Florian/freebie-google-material-design-shadow-helper-2a0501295a2d#.wyvbmcq10

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of the negative Y value suggested by @Vigrond

```
box-shadow: 0px -8px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @Chris C answer but I think, we do not need the first line of code. This is shorter and gives the same effect:

```
box-shadow: -10px 8px 15px lightgray, /*left and bottom*/
            10px 8px 15px lightgray; /*right and bottom*/
```

```css
#note{
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px; left: 30px;
 width:100px; height: 100px;
 background-color: #eee;
 box-shadow: -10px 8px 15px lightgray,
 10px 8px 15px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="note"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid background color, then you can accomplish this by using a combination of `background-color` and `z-index`. The trick is to give the element with `box-shadow` and its previous sibling positioning, then give the previous sibling a background color and set it to have a higher `z-index` so that it's stacked on top of the element with `box-shadow`, in effect covering its top shadow.

You can see a demo here: http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/vNvpKv

If there's no immediate previous sibling to work with, then you can also use a pseudo-element such as `:before` or `:after`: http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/ojJEMj

Comment: It seems like a hack to stack the card on the other to cover up the shadow. Could cause breakage on other break points.

Answer (score 0):

For translucent shadows with hard corners (i.e. no blur radius) I used this:

```
.shadow-no-top {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2), 5px 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.shadow-no-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

This uses a shadow for the left and right parts and adds the :after pseudo content as the bottom shadow. This avoids overlaps which make the shadow darker or missing corners.

However, this does require the background of the element to be solid.