# background shadow for section

Tags: html, css

the requested style is here (image):
[image]

And the developped one is here (image):
[image]

I have used the following style but it's not the same as requested:

```
<section style="box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px #999;">
My content
</section>
```

should i work with box-shadow and change values or there is another attribut for css3 to work with ?

Comment: I think you should have a look on how the box-shadow property works. That's it.

Comment: [Possibly related question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738768/css-box-shadow-on-three-sides-of-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RGB with an alpha channel, e.g.:

```
box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

This makes the shadow black (#000000) with opacity equal to 0.2 (20%).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eG3mL/) with an example close to what you have shown.

Just make sure you check the [browser support](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for `rgba()`.