# Box-Shadow on 3 sides of a div (not on the right side)

Tags: css

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738768/css-box-shadow-on-three-sides-of-a-div) and after multiples attempts to modify the code by the top answer I am still unable to convert it from box-shadow Left/Bottom/Right to Top/Left/Bottom.

This is the Fiddle :

```css
#shadowBox {
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 0 gray, 
        -10px 8px 0 gray, 10px 8px 0 gray;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/>
<div id="shadowBox">Test</div>
```

How can I do that ? I don't understand how this works and manuals don't go further than the classic border-box...

Comment: What did you tried .... Don't only refer link along with that please also provide what did you tried till now?

Comment: #shadowBox {
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 0 gray, -10px -10px 0 gray, -10px 0px 0 gray;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<br/><br/>
<div id="shadowBox">Test</div>
```

CSS: Top/Left/Bottom

```
  #shadowBox {
      background-color: #ddd;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 220px;
      box-shadow: -10px -10px 10px gray, 
          -10px 0px 10px gray, -10px 10px 10px gray;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean sth like this?
i can recommend you a page: cssmatic.com

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -20px 4px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
-moz-box-shadow: -20px 4px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
box-shadow: -20px 4px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
```