# Cover or hide the top of box-shadow so 3 sides are shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a div that when hovered shows another div in it's place, the div shown in it's place has a `box-shadow` of 1 px on all sides, I am trying to cover the top shadow line so that the shadow is only shown on the left, right and bottom.

Edit: I would like the shadow to remain on all 4 sides but to be covered by a div on the top. Not the vertical axis changed. I'm wondering if this is possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/8yeh9cw6/

Is this possible to cover or will it always bring the shadow to the top of anything? Ideally with pure css, otherwise is it possible with jquery or javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get box-shadow on left & right sides only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Try the code below i have added some jQuery

```js
$(".hoveredItem").mouseover(function(){
   
$(this).css({
  "box-shadow":"0px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9)"
  
 });
});
```

```css
.shoptitle {overflow:hidden; background-color:#FFF; padding:15px;}
.parentItem{ height:200px; background-color:#e7e7e7; float:left; margin-left:1px; margin-bottom:1px; }
.I33{width:33.2%; }

.hoveredItem{opacity:0;transition:opacity 0s 0.2s ;position:relative; background-color:#FFF;  width:100%; height:200px; /* box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); */} 
.itemDisplay{ opacity:1;transition:opacity 0s 0.2s;position:relative;}
.parentItem:hover .hoveredItem {opacity:1;  }
.parentItem:hover .itemDisplay{opacity:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shoptitle">Cover top shadow</div>

<div class="parentItem I33">
<div class="itemDisplay"></div>
<div class="hoveredItem">hai</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. But the top shadow still shows slightly by the looks of it with this solution, it looks like 1px of shadow, I am looking for a solution with a div that covers the top shadow / line rather than the vertical axis changed.

Comment: Hello See the updated snippet and let me know you are oky with it or not @Beth

Answer (score 0):

a simplistic solution you can nudge shadow on y-axis

```css
.shoptitle {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px;
}
.parentItem {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.I33 {
    width: 33.2%;
}
.hoveredItem {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.2s;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); */
}
.itemDisplay {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.2s;
    position: relative;
}
.parentItem:hover .hoveredItem {
    opacity: 1;
}
.parentItem:hover .itemDisplay {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shoptitle">Cover top shadow</div>

<div class="parentItem I33">
<div class="itemDisplay"></div>
<div class="hoveredItem">hai</div>
</div>
```

more correct solution.. refer 
[CSS box-shadow on three sides of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738768/css-box-shadow-on-three-sides-of-a-div)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was wanting it to look like but I'm wondering if this can be done by covering the top shadow with a div not by changing to y-axis?